# Draw Arc using javascript

Tags: javascript, drawing

Is there a way to draw an arc using points in JavaScript??

I need to draw an arc when I specify a group of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what platforms you want to support and on the complexity of the drawing, I'd suggest either [DHTML](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm), [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes) (with [ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) for IE).

Although DHTML is cross-browser, canvas seems the way to go for future projects since it is capable of much more and is actually *meant* to be used for graphics.

**Edit:** Either I was wrong when I originally wrote this or ExplorerCanvas *was* actually using flash to render its canvas. but now they've seemed to switch to VML and/or Silverlight. I've edited my answer to exclude that variable dependency. I've also added a stronger suggestion towards canvas.